# Reading and Writing sectors in Assembly using int 13h

Tags: assembly, file-io, operating-system, hard-drive

Ok so I'm having troubles in writing my Assembly Operating system. I read up on the interrupt 0x13 and its functions. And I would like to use this interrupt to load my kernel into memory and i would also like to be able to read and write files to the hard disk. The webpage I read was: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H.

**What I know**

1. DL 0x80 is the 1st hard drive
2. AH 0x42 and 0x43 are the read and write sectors from/to drive
3. I understand the error handling

So with this info could you maybe give me help on implementing this and how i can accomplish my goal and maybe how i can format the drive?

Answer (score 0):

On "ralph brown's interrupt list" you find a lot of information about BIOS and MS-DOS interrupts.

Here is the page about subfunction 0x42 of interrupt 0x13: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0708.htm

(What this page does not mention: Some buggy BIOSes require the "ES" register to be the segment of the transfer buffer so [DS:SI+6] contains the value of ES.)

Comment: Could you possibly give me an example of some code i could use and how to choose proper sectors because this is really confusing me and i dont know why!